# How to move files between Ubuntu and iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, file-transfer

I recently got an iPhone 6s. At home I do not have Windows or Mac computers, only Ubuntu.

Is there a way to transfer files (music, photos, PDF, or really anything actually) between the PC and the phone? It should not involve syncing via an internet service, as I may have the need to transfer large or private files. Also, I do not want to jailbreak the device.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On recent iOS - you can just share out the files over SMB and use the files app to mount the share / move files and folders.

For doing it without a network or file share, here are the older steps using open source libraries to do this without needing to jailbreak the device.

- http://www.libimobiledevice.org/

If you don’t see this included, consider using homebrew to install that package and the http://askubuntu.com people are amazing resources if you run into issues.

- https://askubuntu.com/a/704677/21224

Comment: Since `libimobiledevice` is included in Ubuntu 16.04, you don't have to do anything but plug in the device to your USB and on the first time, you have to confirm **"trust this device" on the iPhone**. Now you can acess the DCIM Folder in Ubuntu. But I found no way to access the Music though, might be a bit more of a hazzle, if someone finds a working answer, please link it here.